# Excel query; drawing on rightmost column in sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel 2016 I have one column full of out-of-date time data (mm:ss) (information in each and every row) and in the second column I have more recent time data (mm:ss) but only in every other row

Is it possible to create a sum using information from the first column (old data), though when data is available in the second column (new data) the new data replaces the old data in the equation?  For example ....

A1 A2
B1
C1 C2
sum = A2+B1+C2

... which becomes updated as the second column is gradually filled in over a period of weeks?

I have just over a hundred rows of information so if there's any way of simplifying the formula regarding this, that would be great

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use =`SUM(IF(B2:B100="",A2:A100,B2:B100))` as a matrix formula (that means, hit CTRL+ALT+RET when entering it, not just RET). replace 100 with your last line of course.

That will make Excel loop for all lines, compare in each line i the cell Bi to "", and if it is blank, use Ai, otherwise use the Bi; and then make a sum of the whole thing.